ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package' in ROS2 Humble Windows
I'm trying to (colcon) build a new C++ package with a binary ROS2 Humble installation in Windows from a Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt, but each time I run "colcon build" in my workspace folder, I get the following error:
Starting >>> my1stpkg
--- stderr: my1stpkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ament_package.templates import get_environment_hook_template_path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package'
CMake Error at C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake:41 (message):
  execute_process(C:/Python38/python.exe
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py
  C:/dev/ros2_dotNET_ws2/build/my1stPkg/ament_cmake_package_templates/templates.cmake)
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_coreConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:15 (find_package)
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmakeConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


CMake Configure step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
---
Failed   <<< my1stpkg [3.64s, exited with code 4294967295]

Summary: 0 packages finished [5.50s]
  1 package failed: my1stpkg
  1 package had stderr output: my1stpkg
WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT
TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)

Yes, I sourced, with the command:
call C:\dev\ros2_humble\local_setup.bat

If I search my computer for files with "ament_package" in the name, I find:
C:\dev\ros2_humble\ros2-windows\share\ament_cmake_core\cmake\core\ament_package.cmake
C:\dev\ros2_humble\ros2-windows\share\ament_cmake_core\cmake\core\ament_package_xml.cmake
C:\dev\ros2_humble\ros2-windows\share\ament_index\resource_index\packages\ament_package
C:\dev\ros2_humble\ros2-windows\share\colcon-core\packages\ament_package
C:\dev\ros2_humble\share\ament_cmake_core\cmake\core\ament_package.cmake
C:\dev\ros2_humble\share\ament_cmake_core\cmake\core\ament_package_xml.cmake
C:\dev\ros2_humble\share\ament_index\resource_index\packages\ament_package
C:\dev\ros2_humble\share\colcon-core\packages\ament_package

I notice when I execute pip3 list it and all "ament" packages I see in my VMware Linux environment are missing.  I tried (re)installing it:
C:\dev\ros2_dotNET_ws2>pip3 install ament_package
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ament_package (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ament_package

I did successfully execute these lines, but they didn't help:
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
pip install --upgrade setuptools

Some file contents, for what they're worth:
package.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>my1stpkg</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="me@company.com">alsome</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>rclcpp</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(my1stpkg)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)

add_executable(cpp_node src/win_node1st.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(cpp_node rclcpp)

install(TARGETS
  cpp_node
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()

I read that ament_package is for Python, so why should I need it if I'm trying to make a C++ package?  Thanks...

Well, it turns out I HADN'T sourced in my dev cmd prompt.  When I did actually call the .bat, I pip3 list showed me the ament packages and I now have a different problem to investigate:
C:\dev\ros2_dotNET_ws2>colcon build
Starting >>> my1stpkg
Failed   <<< my1stpkg [12.0s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [16.8s]
  1 package failed: my1stpkg
WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT
TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)

Hope this helps someone...
